# wordpress custom password change problem

Tags: password

```
if ( !empty($_POST['pass1'] ) && !empty( $_POST['pass2'] ) ) {
            if ( $_POST['pass1'] == $_POST['pass2'] )

    wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $current_user->id, 'user_pass' => esc_attr( $_POST['pass1'] ) ) );

            else
            $error = __('The passwords you entered do not match.  Your password was not updated.', 'frontendprofile');
    }
```

I have used the above code to change users password but  the error was occured

**"Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /hermes/web02/b1441/moo.sharerecipesnowcom/sharerecipesnownet/wp-content/themes/recipe/header.php:13) in /hermes/web02/b1441/moo.sharerecipesnowcom/sharerecipesnownet/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 720"**

Comment: I can't see anything in the above code that would cause that particular error(i could be wrong), what's in the theme's header.php on line 13?

Answer (score 1):

the problem is with your cookies.wp_update_user function is trying to change them after all headers were sent, try to use such code like that:
function my_func(){
   // your code
}
add_action('init','my_func');